# Searching for the type of an expression in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, utop

In Haskell we can search for the type of an expression, such as "+" by entering `:t +` at the terminal.

In utop, how can we determine the type of an expression such as "+"? I have tried entering `+ ;;`  in utop, and this produces `Error: Syntax error`.

Comment: Try `(+)`. Because `+` is an infix operator it can't be used as a standalone expression and requires enclosing in parentheses to pass around as a value.

Comment: Ah that works. So we can find the type of any expression `e` by enclosing it in brackets and appending ``;;`` to it?

Comment: Most expressions don't need brackets. Infix operators do only because the parser otherwise expects further tokens.